# How can I use sudo for gem_package resource

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to install the bluepill service, but when I try to do this without sudo I get the following error.

```
vagrant@leibniz-my-app:~$ gem install bluepill
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Then if I want to reuse the bluepill cookbook for this, I have this problem, because this cookbook use [gem_package](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_gem_package.html) and it hasn't an option sudo.

```
gem_package "bluepill" do
  version node["bluepill"]["version"] if node["bluepill"]["version"]
  action :install
end
```

Then my question is: It is possible to use sudo into a gem_package resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Chef Client always runs as root](http://docs.opscode.com/ctl_chef_client.html) unless you specify otherwise. If you are running as root, you don't need sudo.

Comment: I'm using Chef-solo. It run as root too??

Comment: Yes, it is run as root

Comment: the node tell me that bluepill was installed but when I check into the instance then the  bluepill command is not found.

Comment: What user are you logging in as? Bluepill is installed as a Chef gem, so the CLI isn't natively in the `$PATH`.

Comment: If you're managing things with Chef, you shouldn't ever be "manually" on the system.